# How to feed input string with shape=[?] to tensorflow model using golang

Tags: go, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

Python code of train model:

```
input_schema = dataset_schema.from_feature_spec({
    REVIEW_COLUMN: tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[], dtype=tf.string),
    LABEL_COLUMN: tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[], dtype=tf.int64)
})
```

In python predictions work fine. Example of client:

```
loaded_model = tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, ["serve"], '/tmp/model/export/Servo/1506084916')
input_dict, output_dict =_signature_def_to_tensors(loaded_model.signature_def['default_input_alternative:None'])
start = datetime.datetime.now()
out = sess.run(output_dict, feed_dict={input_dict["inputs"]: ("I went and saw this movie last night",)})
print(out)
print("Time all: ", datetime.datetime.now() - start)
```

But golang client does not work:

```
m, err := tf.LoadSavedModel("/tmp/model/export/Servo/1506084916", []string{"serve"}, &tf.SessionOptions{})
if err != nil {
    panic(fmt.Errorf("load model: %s", err))
}

data := "I went and saw this movie last night"
t, err := tf.NewTensor([]string{data})
if err != nil {
    panic(fmt.Errorf("tensor err: %s", err))
}
fmt.Printf("tensor: %v", t.Shape())

output, err = m.Session.Run(
    map[tf.Output]*tf.Tensor{
        m.Graph.Operation("save_1/StringJoin/inputs_1").Output(0): t,
    }, []tf.Output{
        m.Graph.Operation("linear/binary_logistic_head/predictions/classes").Output(0),
    }, nil,
)
if err != nil {
    panic(fmt.Errorf("run model: %s", err))
}
```

I got error:

> panic: run model: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor
>   'Placeholder' with dtype string and shape [?]
>            [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder_output_shapes=[[?]], dtype=DT_STRING, shape=[?],
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]

How can I present `shape=[?]` tensor with golang? Or I need to change input format of python training script?

UPD:

This string `"save_1/StringJoin/inputs_1"` I received after running this python-code:

```
for n in sess.graph.as_graph_def().node:
    if "inputs" in n.name:
        print(n.name)
```

Output:

```
transform/transform/inputs/review/Placeholder 
transform/transform/inputs/review/Identity 
transform/transform/inputs/label/Placeholder 
transform/transform/inputs/label/Identity 
transform/transform_1/inputs/review/Placeholder 
transform/transform_1/inputs/review/Identity 
transform/transform_1/inputs/label/Placeholder 
transform/transform_1/inputs/label/Identity 
save_1/StringJoin/inputs_1 
save_2/StringJoin/inputs_1
```

Comment: Are you sure that `save_1/StringJoin/inputs_1` is the same vaue of `input_dict["inputs"]` ?

Comment: I updated topic with info about "save_1/StringJoin/inputs_1". I tried other keys, but result was the same - error.

Comment: Can you show the output of `print(input_dict["inputs"])`?

Comment: All input_dict: `{u'inputs': <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder:0' shape=(?,) dtype=string>}`

Comment: Hm.. what happens if you change your Go feed dict from ` m.Graph.Operation("save_1/StringJoin/inputs_1").Output(0): t,` to ` m.Graph.Operation("Placeholder").Output(0): t,` ?

Comment: It seems like works. Does exist rule how to find correct name? I will check more carefully and write result here.

Comment: I write the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells you `You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder'`: this means that the graph can't be built until you feed a value for that placeholder.

In your python code, your feed it at the line:

```
input_dict["inputs"]: ("I went and saw this movie last night",)
```

In fact, `input_dict["inputs"]` is evaluated to: `<tf.Tensor 'Placeholder:0' shape=(?,) dtype=string>`.

In your Go code, instead, you're looking for a tensor named `save_1/StringJoin/inputs_1` that's not the placeholder.

The rule to follow is: use the same input both in Python & Go.

To solve the problem, thus, you just have to extract from the graph the placeholder named `Placeholder` (just like in python) and then use it.

```
m.Graph.Operation("Placeholder").Output(0): t,
```

Also, I suggest you to use a more complete and easy to use wrapper around the tensorflow API: [tfgo](https://github.com/galeone/tfgo)

Answer (score 0):

One more thing. I read TF docs and found this [topic](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model#cli_to_inspect_and_execute_savedmodel)

It helps to find correct input/output keys, example of response:

```
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s): inputs['inputs'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_STRING
    shape: (-1)
    name: Placeholder:0
```

PS/ Posted as answer for focusing